# Deseralize polymorphic JSON string

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have several POJO that all have the same abstract base class. I want to serialize and deserialze without type checks or casts.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT,
    property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = UserEvent.class, name = "user"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SystemEvent.class, name = "system")
})
public abstract class Event {
    private Long id;
    private Date date;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}

@JsonTypeName("user")
public class UserEvent extends Event {

    private String userId;
    private String userName;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}

@JsonTypeName("system")
public class SystemEvent extends Event {

    private String source;

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }
}
```

When I serialize the UserEvent to JSON I get following output with the type name as wrapper object.

```
{
  "user" : {
    "id" : 42,
    "date" : 1568214606656,
    "userId" : "123123",
    "userName" : "Bob"
  }
}
```

So far so good. If I try to deserialize the same JSON object it fails.

```
@Test
void deserializeUserEvent() throws Exception {
    String json =
            "\"user\" : {\n" +
            "    \"id\" : 42,\n" +
            "    \"date\" : 1568211488351,\n" +
            "    \"userId\" : \"123123\",\n" +
            "    \"userName\" : \"Bob\"\n" +
            "  }";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Event event = mapper
            .readerFor(Event.class)
            .readValue(json); // ERROR

    assertSame(UserEvent.class, event.getClass());
}
```

Is it possible to deserialize the concrete type by only declaring the abstract type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use it. I used  Object mapper here to write your object as string.

```
    UserEvent ue = new UserEvent();
    ue.setUserName("Some Username");
    ue.setUserId("userID");
    ue.setDate(new Date());
    ue.setId(123123L);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String userEventString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ue);
```

> {"user":{"id":123123,"date":1568217548148,"userId":"userID","userName":"asdlasd"}}

And read it as:

```
Event event = objectMapper.readValue(userEventString, Event.class);
```

And also ObjectMapper gives you possibility to use:

```
ObjectMapper mapperWithMixin = new ObjectMapper()
        .addMixIn(Event.class, UserEvent.class);
```

where Event.class is your target class, and UserEvent.class is your provided json object.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to deserialize the concrete type by only declaring the abstract type.

The string to be deserialized should be a proper JSON.

```
String json = "{\"user\":{\"id\":42,\"date\":1568216805617,\"userId\":\"123123\",\"userName\":\"Bob\"}}";
Event event = mapper.readValue(json, Event.class);
```

Above code works with the latest version of jackson-databind - 2.9.9.3